# C++: recursive dependency in type alias

Tags: c++, templates, using

I am wondering whether the following code is correct. It compiles and runs on my computer but I feel like there is a recursive dependency of `ShowValueClass` type alias defined in `ValueClass`. Could you please explain how the compiler was able to resolve it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace tmp {
template <typename T>
struct ShowValueClass {
  void ShowValue() { std::cout << T::value << std::endl; }
};
} // namespace tmp

struct ValueClass {
  using ShowValueClass = tmp::ShowValueClass<ValueClass>;
  static constexpr int value = 42;
};

int main() {
  ValueClass::ShowValueClass s;
  s.ShowValue();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no recursion here. Your class `tmp::ShowValueClass<T>` just works for any type `T` having a member `value` that is *printable* by `cout` (has the right `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const T&)` defined).

The fact that you added a type alias called `ShowValueClass` inside `ValueClass` referring to `tmp::ShowValueClass<ValueClass>` changed nothing. In that context, the class acts just like a namespace.

Think about what would happen if you extracted `ShowValueClass` from `ValueClass`:

```
struct ValueClass {
  static constexpr int value = 42;
};

using ShowValueClass = tmp::ShowValueClass<ValueClass>;
```

In that case you would accessed `ShowValueClass` directly in `main()` instead of prefixing it with `ValueClass::`, as in your case. Both the facts that `tmp::ShowValueClass` uses `T::value` and that the type alias `ShowValueClass` is in `ValueClass` are *irrelevant* (there's nothing special about them).

The whole idea of using a class itself as a template parameter of a template class is widespread in C++. Actually, there is pattern called CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) where a class inherits from template class using as parameter the class itself like (from Wikipedia):

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template<class T>
class Base
{
    // methods within Base can use template to access members of Derived
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

You can check the whole article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

### A true recursive dependency example

Now, just to complete the picture, I can show you some code that **won't compile** because of a recursive definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
   static constexpr int val = T::val;
};

struct B {
   static constexpr int val = A<B>::val;
};

int main() { }
```

Here, `A<T>::val` depends on `T::val` and that's OK, but `B::val` depends on `A<B>::val` which expands to `B::val`. In order words, `B::val` depends on `B::val`, which clearly cannot be *resolved*. It's like saying that:

```
x := y(x)
```

with `y(x)` being:

```
y(x) := x.
```

Therefore, `x := x`. Clearly, there is no way to determine a value for `x`.

### A working example using template recursion

Now, if the recursion is properly made and there is a **base case** defined, clearly it can be used even to compute pretty complex things.
Here's a trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <int N>
struct A {
   static constexpr int val = N + A<N - 1>::val;
};

template <>
struct A<0> {
   static constexpr int val = 0;
};

int main() {
   cout << A<10>::val << endl;
}
```

`A<N>::val` is defined recursively as:

```
N + A<N-1>::val if N != 0
0               if N == 0
```

And, as a result, it is the sum of all the numbers from `0` to `N` (inclusive).

Comment: Thank you so much. No only I found an answer to my question but also learned a new concept. It's so exciting!